# Binary Search Tree - complexity of adding nodes

Tags: c++, search, tree, binary, complexity-theory

I have a problem with complexity of BST, I guess. When I try to measure time of adding elements from 10^1 to 10^7, program is getting stuck at 10^5 elements and it takes like 20 seconds to reach that (what probably is not really good, right). I looked at other's adding methods and these look pretty the same.
Here is my adding method:

```
 void addTo(T val)
{
    Node<T>* newnode = new Node<T>(val);
    Node<T>* parent = NULL;
    Node<T>* tmp = root;
    if (tmp != NULL)
    {            
        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            parent = tmp;
            if (newnode->data > tmp->data)
            {
                tmp = tmp->right_child;                    
            }
            else if (newnode->data < tmp->data)
            {
                tmp = tmp->left_child;
            }
        }
        if (newnode->data > parent->data)
        {
            parent->right_child = newnode;
            newnode->parent = parent;
        }
        else
        {
            parent->left_child = newnode;
            newnode->parent = parent;
        }
        size++;
    }
    else
    {
        root = newnode;
        newnode->parent = NULL;
        size++;
    }
}
```

And here is how I measure time in main() function:

```
for (int o = 1; o < MAX_ORDER; o++) //max order is 6 or 7 for example
{
    int max = 100000000; 
    srand(time(0));

    auto totaltime1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    const int n = pow(10, o);
    auto t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int so = rand()%max;
        bstree->addTo(so);
    }
    auto t2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << "Measured time for: " << n << " elements: "<< chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " microseconds\n";
    //cout << "Tree height: " << bstree->printTreeHeight() << " \n";
    bstree->clear();
}
```

So.. where is the problem?

Comment: The first question to such questions on SO, how do you compile the program, build configuration?

Comment: Sorry, but I dont exactly know what do you mean

Comment: Look at the first loop carefully. You get the infinit loop if newnode->data == tmp->data, that is very likely when you have many random values.

Comment: @S.M. I guess that the pupil is never shown anything but 'run'.

Comment: absolute beginner, to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        parent = tmp;
        if (newnode->data > tmp->data) {
            tmp = tmp->right_child;                    
        } else if (newnode->data < tmp->data) {
            tmp = tmp->left_child;
        }
    }
```

If you do

```cpp
addTo(3);
addTo(3);
```

> infinite loop

A possible solution

> if (newnode->data >= tmp->data) {